# ASP.NET and Lucene proximate search

Tags: lucene.net

In Lucene's proximity search the order of the words searched is not maintained.

Is there any way to filter the search so that word1 will always come before word2 in resulted docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the `SpanNearQuery` for that.

http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_4/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/spans/SpanNearQuery.html

```cs
SpanTermQuery tq1 = new SpanTermQuery(new Term("field", "word1"));
SpanTermQuery tq2 = new SpanTermQuery(new Term("field", "word2"));
SpanNearQuery spanNear = new SpanNearQuery(new SpanQuery[]{tq1,tq2}, 2, true);
```

Comment: I used SpanNearQuery in my code but could not got any result. See my other question with title "BooleanQuery worked but not SpanNearQuery". Your help will be well appriciated.